# вылетает симулятор при нажатии на UIAlert

Tags: swift, xcode7

Доброго всем.

у меня проблема возможно что, то не объявленно (незнаю новичек в xcode)

когда я объявляю кнопку и даю ей например UIAlert'ы

```
      // Показывает AlertController
  /*
  @IBAction func ShowACPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Вход", message: "введите данные для входа", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let alertOKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(alertOKAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  */
  @IBAction func showACPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("pressed")
  }
```

при запуске симулятора и нажатии на кнопку вылетает вот такая ошибка при чем в другом проекте я так же пытался вставить UIAlert также вылетало все.
[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема не в `UIAlertController`, а в том что нет функции `ShowACPressed` по логу.

В интерфейс билдере выберите кнопку, при нажатии на которую падает и удалите лишние связи

Comment: спасибо, помогло, зашел в билдере с правого сайдбара, сверху справа последяя иконка и там удалил все привязанные к кнопке функции и заного и левого сайдбара с контролом перетянул во ViewController заного и вуаля все работает. Я знал, что в m$ VS так привязываются кнопки, но не знал, что в xcode тоже. теперь знаю. Спасибо